# Under what circumstances doing a usually bad work with good intention permissible?

Tags: practical-islam, sin

I recently heard this from a cleric :

> Suppose if two friends had some disagreements or fight with each other. Now, to re-establish their friendship bond and unite them, you can separately lie to each of them. For example, if the two persons are A and B, then you can lie and say to A that B praises you very much and vice versa. By this, two friends will re-unite again and lying in this situation is not only just permissible but also a very good act.

But I have also heard that it is not allowed to do bad deeds like stealing money with good intentions like giving the stolen money to charity.

So, I want to know that under what conditions will doing a usually bad deed with good intention be permissible ? ( Assuming that what cleric said was not incompatible with Islam)

Comment: Robbing the bank to give money to charity? 

Comment: Please remember that the purpose of comments is to suggest if a question can be improved in any way and ask clarifications regarding it.